# Do instantiated classes dictate relative paths in OOP?

Tags: php, oop, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm getting my head around OOP and namespacing and I think it's messing with my understanding of absolute and relative paths. Given the following simple directory:

```
X +
  A +
    B +
      FileC
    FileB
```

File B has a class which contains a `file_exists($this->filepath)` call in its constructor. It's looking for `FileC` inside the `B`directory, which is within the same directory as `FileB`.

The $filepath that I assumed would work is `B/FileC`, but that returns false. I then tried `../B/FileC` also false. Then I try `..A/B/FileC`. Again false. I have to go out to `X` to get true: `../X/A/B/FileC`

Obviously, my understanding is off here. I'm 80% sure namespacing has no bearing on `file_exists`. So my next guess—does a calling object affect the realtive file path? Meaning, if FileB's class is being instantiated from within a class defined in another folder in the same directory as `A`, does that class then dictate the relative path?

Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: I think this has nothing with OOP but I also experienced relative directories structure problems. The only way I was able to solve this is using absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with OOP...

file_exists runs off your current running path, that means you need to call the

`dirname(__FILE__)` to understand your current path, and understand where the files you are trying to access reside in relation to the current running path.
Just because you are using class A or file B doesn't mean you can assume you're running in that directory.

It's only about files and paths in php.

I think that you current directory depends a lot on which file you're calling and from what directory, and not so much about the include files I assume you're using.

How about using absolute paths (without hardcoding of course) instead?

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/your/A/B/C'
```

Comment: This is how I'm moving forward for now, but was hoping to understand why the simple path isn't working.

Comment: try also playing around with http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php that might perhaps give you a better understand of your file structure..